# i got the following error : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'detectMultiScale' to show image in python?

Tags: python, image-recognition, opencv

```py
import cv2

videoCam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

face = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
nose = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml')
mouth = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml')

while True:
    cond, frame = videoCam.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (154, 154))

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    muka = face.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in muka:
        cv2.rectangle(gray, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 5)

        roi_warna = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        mata = eye.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        nose = nose.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        mouth = mouth.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (mx,my,mw,mh)in mata:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_warna, (mx,my), (mx+mw, my+mh), (255,255,0), 2)
        for (nx, ny, nw, nh)in nose:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_warna, (nx, ny), (nx + nw, ny + nh), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        for (bx, by, bw, bh)in mouth:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_warna,(bx,by),(bx+bw,by+bh),(0,0,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('Face dan Eye detection', frame)


    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == ord('q'):
        break

videoCam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please fix the format and expand more on what you intend to do with this code and if possible add an example of the file you are working with.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Thanks the error has solved been solved :)